# Why is !found instead of found necessary in the while loop condition of this linear search of an array?

Tags: java

I'm just starting with Java and have a pretty silly question about a linear search of array.
Why is it necessary to put `!found` and not just `found` in the while loop condition? I'm a bit confused because in my thinking, the while loop should run when we have not found the target and the index is smaller than the array length, so it should be `while((found)&&(index<myArray.length))` instead?

```java
public class LinearSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int target = 2;
        boolean found = false;
        int index = 0;
        int indexOfTarget = -1;
        int [] myArray = {18,38,2,20,24,14,5};
        while ((!found)&&(index<myArray.length)) {
            if (myArray[index]==target) {
                indexOfTarget=index;
                found = true;
            }
            index++;
        }
        if(found) System.out.println("Found element at position "+indexOfTarget);
        else System.out.println("Target not found");
    }

}
```

Comment: If it was `while (found)` it would never run once, because found is initialized to false. I'm a bit confused of your perspective. You say it should run "while we have not found the target". That translates exactly to: `while( !found ...`

Comment: AHH I get it now, thank you! I feel stupid now :D

Answer (score -1):

Your code also works, as long as you make sure you break out of the loop when the index reaches the array's limit.
There are many ways to understand this.

```java
//using !found, you need to break 
while (!found) {
   if (myArray[index]==target) {
       indexOfTarget=index;
       found = true;
       break;//also break when you find a match
   }
   index++;
   if (index == myArray.length) break;
}
``
```